# Pantheon (Elementary Desktop) not loading

Tags: 14.04, desktop-environments, elementary

I add to repository this: ppa:elementary-os/daily and installed elementary-desktop

Next log off -> select Pantheon -> click login = nothing. Empty screen with my wallpaper..

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `pantheon-shell`.

Before installing add these two `ppa` in your system:

```
ppa:ricotz/testing

ppa:elementary-os/testing
```

Note that they are unstable now.